# How to install pywhatkit?

Tags: python

i am having a problem  regarding installing pywhatkit in python
version - pycharm 2016, python 3.3.0

Executed command:-
`pip install --user pywhatkit`

The command output is:-

```
Collecting pywhatkit
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6b/f8/7f2763b08be029e5b199178c99b2017533e23c1d9e5e07229fd078e1a183/pywhatkit-5.4.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pywhatkit\setup.py", line 12, in <module>
        with open("requirements.txt", "r") as f:
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
    
    ----------------------------------------

DEPRECATION: Python 3.3 supported has been deprecated and support for it will be dropped in the future. Please upgrade your Python.
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pywhatkit\
```

I was trying to install it by:

- pressing ctrl + alt +s
- and then clicking on project interpreter
- and then clicking on the '+' icon and installing it from there

Comment: i ran this on my local and it worked fine; not sure why you're getting **No such file or directory: requirements.txt**. With your pip install command, it doesn't have anything to do with your requirements.txt. Did you run this on your terminal or thru some IDE?>

Answer (score 0):

It looks like package has wrong path for requirements - maybe try to install lower version ?

Or if not try gihtub installation: https://github.com/Ankit404butfound/PyWhatKit/wiki

Answer (score 0):

Try running the line:
`pip install pywhatkit`

(At least that is the line I ran when I installed it.)